# Juristic background for heroku hosted repositories

Tags: heroku, hosting, web-hosting

Heroku provides a quite easy way to host simple websites (e.g. via Nodejs, Expressjs) by linking a (public) github reposiory. The result is available via the subdomain appname.herokuapp.com.

What is the juristic background for that (or are there any precedent cases), as for example in Germany every webpage needs to provide an imprint and a privacy statement which I assume not many repositories provide. I assume heroku is not responsible for the content of their domain, are they?

Comment: Note SO doesn't offer legal advice.

Comment: thanks for that hint, I did not expect a watertight advice, more like a general answer where to have a look at/ what general concepts are in behind. If this expectation is also "too much" for SO, let me know, so I can delete the question.